# AWS Aurora MYSQL how to deal with growing table

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-aurora, archiving

I have a MySQL table that is growing quite fast and I was wondering what would be the best approach regarding **ARCHIVING** not needed data moving forward.
The table has data that is 2 years old, but we only need the data for last year onwards.
At the moment, the table has about 4 million rows and is 2.2GB in size.

*DB specs:*

**Engine version**

5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.2

**Instance class**

db.r4.xlarge

**vCPU**

4

**RAM**

30.5 GB

Would anyone have any input in that regard?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table were *already* partitioned by, say, month, archiving would be relatively efficient.

In the absence of that prep work, I recommend:

**PARTITION BY RANGE(..)**

1. Create a new table that is partitioned; cf [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)
2. Copy the data since a year ago into that table.
3. Drop the current table
4. Work on creating a regular monthly process involving "transportable tablespaces".  Or, if you don't need to keep the old data, then plan on just `DROP PARTITION` (and add a new partition).  (See link above.)

**Big DELETE**

If, instead, you choose to do something that involves `DELETEing` millions of rows, I strongly suggest chunking the operation:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

The above does not say where you will send the data you have removed from this main table.  What is your plan for that?